# Box2d - How often should i use Step in my window loop?

Tags: c++, box2d

i'm trying to make a simple game with box2d and c++.
My question is, how often should i use the world->Step function?
Should i use it only 1 time in the loop or after every draw?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [Box2D documentation](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf) the `step()` function should be called to resolve the time base (emphasis mine):

> Note that the time step and the iteration count are completely unrelated. An iteration is not a sub-step.
>   One solver iteration is a singe pass over all the constraints within a time step. You can have multiple
>   passes over the constraints within a single time step.
>
> We are now ready to begin the simulation loop. In your game the simulation loop can be merged with
>   your game loop. In each pass through your game loop you call b2World::Step. **Just one call is usually
>   enough**, depending on your frame rate and your physics time step.

Comment: Hey, but if i use it once, my player is falling very slowly.